# Increasing fps & decreasing duration while streaming using VLC

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc, frame-rate

Hello Stackoverflow :3

I have been trying to increase the fps and effectively decreasing the duration while increasing the speed when streaming a video from my hard drive using vlc. I would like to transcode **while** I am streaming if possible. I can already speed up the video before streaming however that is not the desired task.

The command I use for streaming regularly is (note xxx.xxx.x.xxx represents my ip):

```
vlc --intf dummy -vvv /Users/amr/Downloads/bigbangsample.mp4 --sout '#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1236/test.sdp}'
```

After following tips from [Change Frames Per Second for VLC Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187948/change-frames-per-second-for-vlc-stream) I have tried transcoding using the command:

```
vlc --intf dummy -vvv /Users/amr/Downloads/bigbangsample.mp4 --sout='#transcode{fps=60}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1236/test.sdp}'
```

Although I can still view the stream with no warnings or errors the video does not seem to be affected at all.

I am unsure if my command is wrong or if the fps really has been changed but by copying the frames to keep the duration the same. I am new to vlc and video processing and would appreciate any input.

UPDATE:
ffprobe (see below) seems to show that the fps hasn't changed. Is there a standard way to change stream fps ?

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1236/test.sdp':

  Metadata:
    title           : Unnamed
    comment         : N/A
  Duration: N/A, start: 21.377938, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, progressive), 720x404 [SAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, I think that you have to add the `vcodec`, even if it's the same. so try `vlc --intf dummy -vvv /Users/amr/Downloads/bigbangsample.mp4 --sout='#transcode{vcoded=h264,fps=60}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1236/test.sdp}' (worked for me at list)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to add the `vcodec`, even if it's the same. So try

```
vlc --intf dummy -vvv /Users/amr/Downloads/bigbangsample.mp4 --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,fps=60}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1236/test.sdp}'
```

(worked for me at least)

Comment: Yes it still streams but if you watch the stream, or alliteratively ffprobe it, it still plays at the regular fps (around 24-30), Or did you get something else ? (cool profile pic btw XD)

Comment: thanks:), I tried it on mpeg file and it works (changes the fps),  maybe you can use `ffmpeg` command instead, if `vlc` doesn't work.

Comment: hmmm interesting. I will try it on an mpeg file - have you tried it on avi or mp4 files by any chance ?